# ASP.NET 5 authentication with ADFS 3

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, adfs3.0

I'd want to create an ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 application with authentication on ADFS 3.0.

The new ASP.NET Security middleware don't support WsFederation authentication.
ADFS 3.0 don't support OpenID connect.

Are there working scenarios to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a nuget package to add ADFS specific oauth to ASP.NET Core :
[Codinlab.AspNetCore.Authentication.AdfsOAuth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Codinlab.AspNetCore.Authentication.AdfsOAuth/)

Answer (score 0):

1-create new asp.net MVC application using visual studio 2013
2-click on change authentication
3-choose Organizational accounts
4-from drop-down choose On-Premises
5-enter your ADFS meta URL in this text-box "On-Premises Authority"

source:
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: in case you want to SSO with Office 365 flow this [tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/09/11/step-by-step-setting-up-ad-fs-and-enabling-single-sign-on-to-office-365.aspx)